# How to bring disowned command back into current terminal (stdout)

Tags: terminal, stdout

I executed a command which I then disowned so that it can continue to run in the background, even if I closed the terminal.

The command is:

```shell
badblocks -v -s -w /dev/sdb > badblocks_result.txt 2>&1 & disown
```

The command is running with a PID of `1146`.

How do I bring that back into the current terminal that I am using if I would like to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the command and not kill it using the PID?

Comment: "if i would like to CTRL-C the command and not kill it using the PID" – What is the point? Upon Ctrl+c `badblocks` would get SIGINT just like from `kill -s INT 1146`, it couldn't tell the difference. In general Ctrl+c sends SIGINT to a process group, so if you target just one process with `kill -s INT`, something may misbehave ([example](https://superuser.com/q/1829830/432690)); but here there should be no issues, `badblocks` is most likely the only process in its process group. Why do you want Ctrl+c and not `kill`? If you really want: [`reptyr`](https://superuser.com/a/1231033/432690).

Comment: As @KamilMaciorowski says there's no difference between using `kill` and ctrl+c. To be able to detach programs and re-attach them later look at `screen` or `tmux`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to add a process to the job list in bash (e.g. to reverse "disown")?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215643/is-it-possible-to-add-a-process-to-the-job-list-in-bash-e-g-to-reverse-disown)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Interestingly, i thought that it would actually know the difference. I don't actually want to kill it but if i need to i have the solution thanks to you. As badblocks usually states where and at what block it got stopped at. Which would hen output to the text file. The solution would be to use the `reptyr`

Comment: Not answering the question directly, but for next time. The correct tool for this would be `screen` or `tmux`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to use the following answer https://superuser.com/a/1231033/432690

The answer was supplied by @Kamil Maciorowski comment.

> "If I would like to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> the command and not kill it using the PID" – What is the point?
>
> Upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> badblocks would get `SIGINT` just like from `kill -s INT 1146`, it couldn't tell the difference. In general <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sends `SIGINT` to a process group, so if you target just one process with `kill -s INT`, something may misbehave (example); but here there should be no issues, `badblocks` is most likely the only process in its process group.
>
> Why do you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and not kill? If you really want: [`reptyr`](https://superuser.com/a/1231033/432690).