# Silently timeout command in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, timeout

This is an oft-asked question:

- [Super User: Loop: Start program and kill after time out](https://superuser.com/questions/175550/loop-start-program-and-kill-after-time-out)
- [SO: How to kill a child process after a given timeout in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash)
- [SO: How to run a process with a timeout in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224939/how-to-run-a-process-with-a-timeout-in-bash)

This time, I'm adding a twist. I need to do this in `zsh`. Additionally, the solution:

- Must be silent (i.e. no job control messages)
- Must be portable (i.e. as close to pure `zsh` as possible. Assume no `coreutils`)
- Should be correct (see notes)
- **Should behave like GNU `timeout`**

---

## On correctness:

Starting a process, waiting for a while, and killing its PID is wrong. It's wrong because it's possible for the process we're timing to die and a new process to start with the same PID later if the timeout is log, or the system is low on PIDs. In practice, this rarely happens, but it would be nice if there was a cleaner way to track when the process has terminated and only kill it if it has not.

Comment: Related: [How can I kill a process and be sure the PID hasn't been reused](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181001). As shown there GNU timeout is not foolproof and may kill the wrong process.

Comment: I am curious to know why you cannot simply use coreutils' "timeout" tool. Maybe it could be added as an internal in zsh if you really want to save an external command execution.

Answer (score 1):

First what comes to my mind is to get PID after process creation, use `zstat` tool (see `man zshmodules`) to get get process timestamp, e.g. `zstat '+mtime' /proc/PID`, and after desired amount of time check if timestamp for given `/proc/PID` has no changed - if yes kill the job.

Comment: Thanks this is a great idea. I'm having a bit of trouble tying it all together. In particular, I'd like to preserve the stream behavior of STDOUT, like GNU `timeout` does, and I'm having a hard time with that.