# How to avoid killing a wrong process when using PID number for killing?

Tags: process, kill

I do start a long-running background process within a Bash script. I save the PID number inside a variable after sending the process to background and I use that PID number to kill that process when necessary.

However, if that background process terminates somehow before my script kills it and system assigns the same PID number to a newly created process, when I use that number to kill that background process, this action would probably kill that newly created process (depending on permissions, of course).

A used PID number would not be assigned to any newly created process in a short time, I'm aware of that, but my script is running for weeks, so it's  possible.

How can I prevent such an accident from happening?

Comment: You don't have to kill it with the command `kill PID`, just try the more explicit `pkill <name>` command. Would this solve your problem?

Comment: You can run the background process with some special environment variable. Then on Linux, check the environment variable via `/proc/PID/environ`, or maybe just checking `/proc/PID/exe` is sufficient?

Comment: What operating system(s) do you need to support?

Comment: @Mikel It needs to be accomplished on Linux only.

Comment: @QuoraFeans I wouldn't know the name of the background process because this parent script might be run simultaneously, so there might be many of that background processes exist at the same time. If I use the name, one parent would kill all other scripts' background processes.

Comment: @Mikel You are suggesting labeling each background process with a unique ID through an environment variable? That's clever. Why don't you move your comment to an answer?

Comment: Since you’re on Linux, have you looked into pid namespaces? If you start your long-running job in a new pid namespace, you can kill it inside that namespace with no risk of killing anything else. You’d have to keep track of the namespace...

Comment: Related: [grep command giving false positive results](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/604730)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combine the PID with timestamp of /proc/<PID> into a uniq id, without worrying about killing wrong PID.

Save $PID:

```
echo $PID $(stat --format %Z /proc/$PID/comm) > pid
```

Kill $PID safely:

```
read PID TIMESTAMP < pid
[[ $(stat --format %Z /proc/$PID/comm) != $TIMESTAMP ]] || kill -SIGKILL $PID
```

By this way, even the $PID get recycled for another process, its creation time (timestamp of /proc/$PID/comm) will be different, so it is impossible to duplicate.

PS: the `[[ ... ]] || cmd` means if `[[ ]]` is true then do nothing, otherwise run `cmd`.

EDIT: We do have other many workarounds, but I think why not solve it directly? This should be the simplest direct way, no need background service, no need advanced system libararies such as systemd which is not well supported in most containers. I have used this way in a product which need interrupt other ongoing processes.

EDIT2: When you kill your background processes, you'd better start your background process in a separate process group, such as `setsid background_process &`, then in any sub-process of the background_process, you can get the process group id by `ps -o pgid= $$`, then in the killer side kill the process group id, then all sub processes will be killed atomically. Otherwise, you kill a normal process id, then its children will still be alive, and even using `pkill -P parant_pid` it will still have a chance that a new children escapes.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, the `pkill` utility might be of use.

Since you say "bash script" you would most likely have to run `pkill bash` - And that is something you shouldn't do.

Instead, you can use `pkill -f <name>`, which will use the full process name to match. So assuming your task is `bash /home/me/my_script.sh`, you can use the following:

```
pkill -f -e my_script.sh
```

The `-e` is optional and simply prints out what is killed.

---

Alternative:

Save the following script as`/usr/bin/mykill` (or anywhere you want):

```
#!/bin/bash
mypid="$1"
if [[ ! -f /proc/$mypid/cmdline ]]; then
    echo "Process ID not found."
    exit 1
else
    echo "About to kill $(cat /proc/$mypid/cmdline)"
    echo "Press enter if you want to kill that process"
    read -p "Press CTRL-C if you don't want that"
    kill $mypid
fi
```

And run it as `mykill <pid>`

Comment: Using the name of the background process does not seem to be an option, as I explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610435/how-to-avoid-killing-a-wrong-process-when-using-pid-number-for-killing/610450#comment1139582_610435

Answer (score 2):

If your background process is under your control, add extra identification to its command line as a label, which you can keep a copy of alongside the Pid, and later check in `ps -o args myPid`.

I use an option like `--unique "${myTag}"`

I derive myTag from either `uuidgen`, or a `date` to nanosecond accuracy. If it is an ssh job, include the local hostname.

If you cannot introduce a new option:

.. Use `date +%s` to get the start time of the job, and store with the Pid.

.. Use `ps -o etimes` to get the elapsed time in seconds of the process.

.. Compare with the current `date +%s` (probably with a few seconds tolerance).

Either method, in conjunction with the Pid, should have negligible probability of error.

Comment: Only weakness of the "checking the run time solution" might be that if the date settings of the computer is altered (by intention) during the waiting period, the parent script would believe that the PID doesn't belong to itself.

Comment: @ceremcem I learned recently that VMs can run the clock in slo-mo. I use NTP and avoid VMs so I tend to trust my `date` output. An uncooperative child can evade all searches -- e.g. by saving its state to a file, exec () itself under a different name, and reload the state. You might monitor it every minute and record the time it disappeared, so a re-use of the Pid would be known to be a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `jobs` command to check if that job was terminated or not.
The output looks like the following:

```
➜  ~ vim test.txt &
[1] 5634
➜  ~
[1]  + 5634 suspended (tty output)  vim test.txt
➜  ~ jobs
[1]  + suspended (tty output)  vim test.txt
➜  ~ kill -9 5634
[1]  + 5634 killed     vim test.txt
➜  ~ jobs
➜  ~
```

In this case the `vim test.txt` is in the second column and can be used to check if the process is still the same and the program is the correct one, if `jobs` does not return the target program you can modify your script to avoid killing the `PID`.

Comment: Note that OP is talking about a script, not interactive use.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that this is not possible, in general.  And I would not recommend killing by-name with `pkill` if you can avoid it (what if you legitimately want multiple instances of some command to have individual timeouts?).  I do not see how the answer regarding `jobs` does anything at all to eliminate the race condition; using `jobs` and then `kill` is not atomic.

However, we can use Process Group IDs (`PGID`s) if job control is enabled, or use a subshell and kill by Process Parent ID (`PPID`) if that is not an option.  See my post here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/649320/464414

I'll only excerpt the preferred method and paste it here; see the above post for notes and alternatives.

UPDATED: The below version now works with pipes

```bsh
timeOut() {
    checkArgs() { [ $(( ${1} )) -gt 0 -a "${*:2}" ]; }
    jobControlEnabled() { expr "${-}" : '.*m' >/dev/null; }
    terminalFDs() { [ -t 0 -a -t 1 ]; }
    groupLeader() { sh -c 'expr `ps -o pgid= ${PPID}` : "${PPID}" >/dev/null;'; }
    timeOutImpl() {
        groupLeader || { echo "Job control error - not group leader!"; return -1; }
        KILL_SUB="kill -- -`sh -c 'echo ${PPID}'`"
        { sleep ${1}; ${KILL_SUB}; } &
        "${@:2}"; ${KILL_SUB}
    }
    checkArgs "${@}" || { echo "Usage: timeOut <delay> <command>"; return -1; }
    if jobControlEnabled && terminalFDs; then
        ( timeOutImpl "${@}"; )
    else
        ( set -m; ( timeOutImpl "${@}"; ); )
    fi
}
```