# How to prevent Linux from using a specific PID number for any newly created process?

Tags: linux, process

I'd like to introduce a solution for the problem originally described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610435/how-to-avoid-killing-a-wrong-process-when-using-pid-number-for-killing/610450?noredirect=1#comment1139758_610450):

> `pkill` is not an atomic operation, not by a long stretch. In the while since pkill -P 666 foo has determined that pid 667 is the child of 666 named foo (which on e.g. Linux it does by opening and reading multiple files in the /proc fs) until it actually calls the kill(2) system call, the process could've already terminated and its pid could've been already reused.

In order to make `pkill -P XXX` operation safe (like transactions in SQL) I'd like to implement the [Two Phase Commit Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol):

- Check if the process is child of `THE_PARENT` process.
- If "yes", mark the PID of the child process as "DO_NOT_REUSE".
- Check if the process is still the child of `THE_PARENT` process.
- If "yes", kill the child process, if still possible.
- Remove the `DO_NOT_USE` flag for that PID number.

For that purpose, can I mark a PID number as "can not be used"?

Comment: How would you avoid a race after the `DO_NOT_USE` removal?

Comment: There are provisions in preparation to avoid races. Userland tools will have to follow somehow I guess: [Adding the pidfd abstraction to the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/801319/), (and related spinoffs: [Grabbing file descriptors with pidfd_getfd()](https://lwn.net/Articles/808997/))

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't understand how there will be a race state after the `DO_NOT_USE` removal. OS will just use that PID as usual. What is the point I may be missing?

Comment: I thought I’d found a racing scenario but nothing I can think of now causes any issue (assuming this is implemented with the help of the kernel).

Answer (score 0):

The kernel will not reuse a pid until it 'wraps around'.

You can check the pid_max with `cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` (`4194304` on my system).

So it is very unlikely to reuse a pid in the time it takes to kill the process.

> ```
>    /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max (since Linux 2.5.34)
>        This file specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e.,
>        the value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID).
>        PIDs greater than this value are not allocated; thus, the
>        value in this file also acts as a system-wide limit on the
>        total number of processes and threads.  The default value for
>        this file, 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as on ear‐
>        lier kernels.  On 32-bit platforms, 32768 is the maximum value
>        for pid_max.  On 64-bit systems, pid_max can be set to any
>        value up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT, approximately 4 million).
> ```